# Como implementar um gráfico usando amCharts?

Tags: javascript, java, xml

Estou tentando implementar um gráfico de barra/coluna utilizando a ferramenta [própria](http://extra.amcharts.com/editor/column/) do amCharts que utiliza o XML, mas não estou conseguindo editá-lo para ficar com uma barra específica. Qual seria solução mais simples para implementação usando o amCharts?

Comment: O que você quer dizer por "específica"? De uma cor ou formato diferente, por exemplo?

Comment: sim, quero que mostre apenas uma barra/coluna por entidade. Lembrando que é feito através do xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode tentar utilizar apenas um conjunto de dados (um nó `graph`). Por exemplo, no XML Data use algo como o seguinte:

```xml
<chart>
  <series>
    <value xid="0">Entidade 1</value>
    <value xid="1">Entidade 2</value>
    <value xid="2">Entidade 3</value>
    <value xid="3">Entidade 4</value>
    <value xid="4">Entidade 5</value>
  </series>
  <graphs>
    <graph gid="0">
      <value xid="0">69</value>
      <value xid="1">101</value>
      <value xid="2">66</value>
      <value xid="3">23</value>
      <value xid="4">41</value>
    </graph>
  </graphs>
</chart>
```

Lembrando que o ID (e também o nome e a cor) do conjunto de dados é definido no Settings XML:

```
...
<graph gid="0">
    <title>Meu Gráfico</title>
    <color>ADD981</color>
</graph>
...
```

Resultando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]